# How to sert autoReorg=false

Tags: liquibase

Where can I specify autoReorg=false. 
I see that by default autoReorg is set to true.
Attempting to set the property in a properties file or command line results in an error:
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unknown parameter: 'autoReorg'

I got the above error message using Liquibase 3.5.3 and 3.6.2.
I need to be able to specify autoReorg=false when working with DB2.

Answer (score 1):

Its currently not possible to set this via properties or commandline. You must pass it as a java property.

https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3257

> Problem It is not possible to turn off automatically generated reorg
>   statements for DB2 using liquibase properties. This is because in
>   Main.java, there is no field for the property 'autoReorg', and hence
>   liquibase throws a CommandLineParsingException in
>   parsePropertiesFile().
>
> Expected result Reorg statements should not be generated for DB2 when
>   the liquibase property file contains the property autoReorg=false or
>   when this property is passed via the command line.
>
> Workaround A workaround is to set the property
>   -Dliquibase.autoReorg=false as a java property.